# Build criteria query with joins and custom parameters

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I need to build following query using JPA and criteria query but I stuck on join conditions. The query is:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM output cu
JOIN user ur ON cu.id = ur.id AND cu.key = ur.key 
JOIN product p ON cu.id = p.id AND cu.key = p.key
WHERE p.refreshtimestamp IS NOT NULL AND cu.active = true
```

So far I have following, but how to apply join conditions:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Output> cq = cb.createQuery(Output.class);
    Root<Output> output= cq.from(Output.class);
    Join<Output, User> user = output.join("user", JoinType.INNER);
    Join<User, Product> product = user.join("product", JoinType.INNER);
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Following should help.

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Product> criteria = builder.createQuery(Product.class);

Root<Output> outputRoot = criteria.from(Output.class);
Root<User> userRoot = criteria.from(User.class);
Root<Product> productRoot = criteria.from(Product.class);

Predicate[] predictes = {
    builder.equal(outputRoot.get("id"), userRoot.get("key")),
    builder.equal(productRoot.get("id"), userRoot.get("key")),
    builder.notEqual(productRoot.get("refreshtimestamp"), null), // not sure about null
    builder.equal(outputRoot.get("active"), true)
};

criteria.select(productRoot);
criteria.where(builder.and(predicates));
```

Although this would produce `cross joins` query, it will work because of `where` clause making it work like `inner join` as you require.